# Cannot boot after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

After I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, it can't boot. I don't know why. Because when I installed it, it said installation succeeded but when I restart, it only shows me the Ubuntu desktop image.

My laptop specifics:

- Samsung Rv520
- 640 GB HDD
- 4 GB RAM
- Processor: Intel Core i3
- Intel HD 1.6 GB

Comment: It starts, you get a page displayed, but are **not** prompted for a login/password?  (Not clear enough from your description.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the rescue option (Ubuntu boot repair) from the LiveCD, as you may be missing the bootloader (GRUB).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your new computer is still too new for Ubuntu 12.04's drivers and packages. I've experienced this on other computers and the most likely period of time when a stable release for Ubuntu Linux is six months after your purchase. I ran a dual-boot configuration with Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS and Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and the grub loader started to quit working. If you have critical data on your Windows 7 partition, send me a message and I will give you the link to Microsoft Answers, in order to restore the Windows 7 partition.